# Como consumir uma API utilizando Angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular-6

Como pegar o retorno do post através do Component?

Código:

## service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'


import { error } from 'selenium-webdriver';

@Injectable()
export class AppService{
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

    sendEmail(email){
         return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/backendteste/db/email.php?acao=sendEmail',email)
        .subscribe((data)=>{
            console.log('pegando retorno do backend ',data);    
        },(error)=>{
            console.log('ERROR: ',error);
        });
    }
    clear(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

## component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        statusEmail:string;
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private appService: AppService) { }

        enviarEmail(form){
            this.appService.sendEmail(form);
           // console.log(form);
       }
    }
```

## html

```
<div class="" *ngIf="statusEmail">
            <i class="rounded-x fa fa-check"></i>
            <p>Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso !</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: Se não tem problema em ler em inglês tem uma ótima explicação aqui sobre respostas http usando observables https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

Comment: @Herick qual é o retorno do post?

Answer (score 0):

É só você fazer o subscribe:

```
enviarEmail(form){
  this.appService.sendEmail(form).subscribe(response => {
    // retorno do http.post
  });
}
```

Leia mais sobre requições http com Angular em: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-heroes-with-httpclient